# Smallest sum of a sequence of numbers in the array. Do not need code

Tags: c

> Write a function called smallest_sum_sequence() that accepts an array
>   of signed integers and the number of items in the array as arguments,
>   and returns the smallest sum of a sequence of numbers in the array. A
>   sequence is defined as a single item or multiple items that are in
>   adjacent memory locations.

This is obviously homework, I do not need anyone to write the code for me just an explanation of what they actually are looking for, as it is worded weirdly in my opinion.

I think what they are wanting is:

```
    Given an array and the total items in the array.

    Have the user input a sequence of values for the array ( array[7] -> array[9] )

    return smallest sum
```

Then determine the smallest sum? Is that supposed to be the smallest value or the smallest combination of items? The first sounds too easy and the second doesn't make sense even if you have negatives.

Am looking for any sort of enlightenment.

Comment: we can't read your lecturers mind either :)  voting to close as "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: I don't think they want user input, but I agree that it it not clear at all what they are asking for.

Comment: Haha, I am glad I am not the only one having troubles trying to understand what they are asking! I will go with my original assumption and put in a comment that says the question doesn't make much sense and I did the best I could with it.

Comment: don't be shy about asking for clarification, and even a trivial example of wtf the instructor is talking about. its their *job* to teach you.

Comment: If there are no negative numbers in the array, then the answer would be the smallest number in the array.  If there are negative numbers, then the smallest sum would be a range that included one or more of those negative numbers, possibly with some positive numbers between them.  For example, in an array `{ 1, -12, 3, -7, 0 }` , the smallest sum would be from adding the numbers `-12, 3, -7` to give a value of -16 (I suppose the 0 could be included in the set or not).

Comment: @BridgerWinter : if you find out what they want, let us know here. I'm curious.

Comment: He is an excellent professor, our last class is tomorrow so I will ask him then about what the heck he actually wanted from that. For the life of me I can't even imagine what I am supposed to do.

Comment: @MichaelBurr 's comment looks rather promising.

Comment: @MichaelWalz indeed. I completely agree. The specific inclusion of *signed* in the integer description of the question is a solid hint Mr. Burr is on to something.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Okay, I think that makes sense. So it would be loop through the array and attempt to find the sequence that generates the smallest sum. Interesting. Thank you so much! I will work on that then!

Comment: @Bridger: it's probably a trickier problem to solve that might appear at first glance. For example, how to find the range of elements that sum to the smallest number in this array isn't obvious (at least to me): `{-1, 5, 6, -10, 4, -15, 2, -7, 8, 9, -16 }`

Comment: I couldn't resist the upvote seeing "Do not need code"

Comment: It is not clear if _smallest_ is nearest to 0 or nearest to -infinity. Is -5 smaller or larger than -7 in this case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about how to understand an assignment, not how to solve a programming problem. Possibly try Academia Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2):

You have to sum each int with the next one and find the min of the sum
You can walk like this

```
int min = INT_MAX;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   sum = array[i];
   min = MIN(min, sum);
   for (j = i + 1; j < len ; j++ ) {
      sum += array[j];
      min = MIN(min, sum);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edited as the prior answer was wrong!**

This is how I understand it. Assume you have an array of signed integers, called `A`, consisting of, say, <3, 4, 5>. So n = 3, the length of the array.

Your sequence is defined to be a single (or multiple) items in adjacent memory locations. So A[0] and A[1] would be a sequence as they are in adjacent memory locations, but A[0] and A[2] wouldn't be.

You call your function: smallest_sum_sequence(A, n) with A and n as above.

So your sequences are:
+ of length 1) <3>, <4>, <5>
+ of length 2) <3,4>, <4,5>
+ of length 3) <3, 4, 5>

Hence your function should return 3 in this case.

Comment: Assuming that  the definition of "smallest sum" indicates that a negative number is smaller than a positive number (not absolute magnitudes) then, since the integers in the array are signed, you will need to check all sequences of length n = 2 to n = N (where N is the number of elements in the array and n is the length of the sequence).

Comment: No, `n` is not the length of sequence but the number of the elements in the array. For your example, `n` would be 5. The sequence length could be anywhere between 1 to `n`, not defined in the input.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's true. Should I delete my post or should i try to edit it instead?

Comment: This answer is wrong. You are given the length of the array, not any sequence length

Answer (score 2):

So a sequence is a set of any number of adjacent numbers in an array. In a set like

```
[A B C D E]
```

Any individual could be an answer.  Or `[A B]` could be an answer.  Or `[A B C]`.  Or `[C D E]`. Or even `[A B C D E]`.  But, definitely not `[A D E]` since `A` is not adjacent to `D` in the original set.  Easy.

Now you have to write code that will compare the sum of the values in every possible adjacent sequence, in any set of numbers (given the size of that set beforehand).

Answer (score 1):

With an array of signed integers it is possible that a larger sequence produces a smaller sum than a single number or a pair.

To find out you need to produce all possible sequences:

```
Start with first number alone, then first and second, then first, second and third.

Then start with second number ...

Then the sum of each sequence.
```

Return smallest sum (and probably the matching sequence)

Comment: See @Orel's answer for code which does this

Answer (score 0):

Let's look closely at the requirements:

> Write a function ... smallest_sum_sequence() that accepts **(1)** an
>   array of signed integers and **(2)** the number of items in the array
>   as arguments, and **(3)** returns the smallest sum of a sequence of
>   numbers in the array.
>
> A sequence is defined as a **single item** or **multiple items ... in
>   adjacent memory locations**.

Taking them one at a time, you know you will write a function that accepts an array of type `int` and then number of items (won't be negative, so `size_t` is a good type). Since it must return a smallest sum, the return type of the function can be `int` as well:

```
int smallest_sum_sequence (int *a, size_t n)
{
    ...
    return ssum;
}
```

That is the basic framework for your function. The next issue to address is the `smallest sum`. Since you are told you are accepting an array of **signed** values, you must presume that the values within the array can be both **negative** and **positive** numbers. You are next told the **sum of the smallest sequence** can be be derived from a **single** or **multiple adjacent** values?

What I interpret this to mean is that you must keep 2 running values. **(1)** the minimum value in the array; and **(2)** a sum of the smallest sequences.

In the arguments you get the number of elements in the array providing you with an easy means to iterate over the array itself:

```
int i = 0;
int min = INT_MAX;   /* largest possible minimum number */
int ssum = INT_MAX;  /* largest possible smallest sum   */

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    min = a[i] < min ? a[i] : min;
    if (i > 0) {
        int tssum = 0;        /* temporary smallest sum */
        /* test adjacent values {
           if adjacent: tssum += a[i]; {
               if no longer adjacent {
                   compare tssum < ssum, if so ssum = tssum;
               }
           }
        } */
    }
}
```

In your first iteration over the array, you have found `min` the **minimum single value** and `ssum` the **sum of the smallest sequence**. Now all that is left is the return:

```
return min < ssum ? min : ssum;
```

That is my impression of what the logic asked for. You may have to adjust the logic of the pseudo-code and you need to figure out how to identify a sequence start/end, but this should at least give you an outline of one way to approach it. Good luck.

Comment: This does not consider *all possible sequences* of lengths 1,2,...n

Comment: What part of `if no longer adjacent` **pseudo code** do you not interpret as being exactly what you say isn't considered? Do you not recognize the bulk of that section as simple thought prompting suggestion not written in anything resembling valid C-syntax? Not to mention the fact that the question has changed since the time of this post.

Comment: The correct solution has two nested loops. I can't find the second loop in your pseudo code.

Comment: This isn't intended as a complete correct solution. The original question said **I do not want full source code!** Did you miss that part? Yes multiple loops are implied, I get what your saying, but you are complaining about something that was left to the user as he had originally requested. If I were to talk about things **not addressed** in your "answer" I would have 4 full comments worth of what you didn't do. However I understand what little part of the problem you were attempting to answer and understand what you weren't.